# React-Native modal does not open

Tags: react-native

I am trying to open the modal through a TouchableOpacity (the second line). I got it to work on a clean application, but when I basically copy and paste to a my current application it does not open at all... Another important point is that this is a card component that is within react-native-deck-swiper. That is my guess for why is won't work.

Top part of my code:

```
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false
    }
  }

  setModalVisible = (visible) => {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible})
  }
```

Bottom Part of my code with the modal

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', paddingLeft: 5, paddingTop: 10}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true)}}>
                  <Icon name="more" style={{fontSize: 40}} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{padding: 5}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>10 miles away</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginTop: 22, flex:1}}>
          <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              alert('Modal has been closed.');
            }}>
            <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
              <View>
                <Text>Hello World!</Text>

                <TouchableHighlight
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                  }}>
                  <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        </View>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `setModalVisible ` ?

Comment: Sorry, just added

Comment: any error? Try logging the state!

Comment: If you have doubt that integrating modal with react-native-deck-swiper creates problem then create separate demo file and check if it works without deck swiper. And if still there is no luck, try to use modal using react-native-modal(https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal).

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind you function in the constructor or use arrow functions or else `this` wont be pointing to your component:

```
setModalVisible = (visible) => {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible})
}
```

Comment: I added that, which didn't fix anything. Is there any chance this error is due to where I place my modal?

Comment: are you getting errors or it's just not doing anything?

Comment: it isn't doing anything. I just made this comment, but my card (the code you are looking at) is in a react-native-deck-swiper. My guess this is why it isn't working. Now I am trying to find workarounds

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, don't use the Arrow function. if you want arrow function then bind it, otherwise use below function.

```
   setModalVisible(visible) {
     this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
   }
```